# udev - difference between += and :=

Tags: linux, udev

I'm trying to understand the `udev` operators so I can create rules for my device, but there seems to be a discrepancy between a couple online sources about the operator that prevents later changes to keys.  Which `udev` operator, if any, will prevent later changes to keys?

There seems to be a discrepancy between the following two sources about the udev operators that prevent later changes to keys.

http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html states that `+:` `ensures that no later rule can have any effect`, but `man udev` states that `:=` will `Assign a value to a key finally; disallow any later changes.`.  `man udev` also states that `"+="` will `Add the value to a key that holds a list of entries.`.  So, which `udev` operator, if any, will prevent later changes to keys?

I tested this question by creating /etc/udev/rules.d/80-test.rules for my USB flash drive.  The rule had the following key-value lines...

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/bin/device_added.sh" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/bin/device_added_2.sh"
```

The executable file `device_added.sh` contains ...

```
`echo "USB device removed  at $(date)" >>/tmp/scripts.log`
```

...and the executable file `device_added_2.sh` contains ...

```
`echo "USB device removed  at $(date)" >>/tmp/scripts_2.log`
```

I registered the changes to udev: `$ sudo udevadm control --reload`
and then I plugged in the USB flash drive.  Then I checked if `/tmp/scripts.log` and `/tmp/scripts_2.log` were created and had the appropriate strings, which they did.  So, it seems that `+=` does NOT prevent later changes to keys.

Then I tested to know if `:=` prevents later changes to keys by subbing `:=` for `+=` in the first key pair of my rule...

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN:="/bin/device_added.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/bin/device_added_2.sh"
```

Then I registered the changes with udev again, unplugged my USB drive, plugged it in, then checked the test log files for updates.  I expected `scripts_2.log` to NOT be updated.  However, it was!  So, it seems that `:=` also does NOT prevent later changes to keys.

**So, can the `+=` and/or `:=` operator(s) prevent later changes to keys some way?  Is there another operator I should be using to prevent later changes?**

It seems unlikely that both `man udev` and `http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html` would be wrong about this, so I'm probably misunderstanding something about this.

I expected `:=` to prevent `scripts_2.log` from being updated.

**UPDATE - 2019-05-12:**
I found [this stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130809/udev-how-to-prevent-further-rules-to-be-run) asking a very similar question, but the two answers provided there do not answer the question in this post.  One answer suggests the use of `GOTO`, which is a workaround that I understand, and the other answer suggests the use of `:=`, which, like the previously mentioned sources, seems false.

**UPDATE - 2019-05-19:**
I just realized that the following statement, in http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html...

```
Additional options
Another assignment which can prove useful is the OPTIONS list. A few options are available:

all_partitions - create all possible partitions for a block device, rather than only those that were initially detected
ignore_device - ignore the event completely
last_rule - ensure that no later rules have any effect

For example, the rule below sets the group ownership on my hard disk node, and ensures that no later rule can have any effect:

KERNEL=="sda", GROUP="disk", OPTIONS+="last_rule"
```

...uses `+=` to add the `last_rule` assignment, which seems it is supposed to have the same effect as `:=`.  So, I edited my rule again to...

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN:="/bin/device_added.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", OPTIONS+="last_rule"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/bin/device_added_2.sh"
```

Then I registered the changes with udev again, unplugged my USB drive, plugged it in, then checked the test log files for updates.  I expected `scripts_2.log` to NOT be updated, but it was.  So, it seems that `OPTIONS +="last_rule"` also does NOT prevent later changes to keys.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the documentation for `:=` is incomplete; it does what is described, but across rule files. I repeated your experiment like so:

In `50-udevoptest.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",  RUN:="/bin/device_added.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/bin/device_added_2.sh"
```

In another rules file from upstream named `73-seat-late.rules`, there is this rule

```
TAG=="uaccess", ENV{MAJOR}!="", RUN{builtin}+="uaccess"
```

Now I test the rules with `udevadm test /sys/...` for a device which both rulesets apply, which gets us:

```
run: '/bin/device_added.sh'
run: '/bin/device_added_2.sh'
run: 'uaccess'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

Then I rename the experiment like so `mv 50-udevoptest.rules 99-udevoptest.rules`, and repeat `udevadm test /sys/...`, which gets us:

```
run: '/bin/device_added.sh'
run: '/bin/device_added_2.sh'
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

(because rule filenames with higher lexical rank receive priority - another ambiguity in the manuals)